# Why does toUpperCase() create spaces as index?

Tags: javascript, uppercase

I'm solving a task writing code to convert a string to spinal case(all-lowercase-words-joined-by-dashes). For example, "This Is Spinal Tap" => this-is-spinal-tap

```js
function spinalCase(str) {
  let newStr = str.split("")
  let arr = []
  for(let i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++){
    if(newStr[i] === newStr[i].toUpperCase()){
      let a = newStr[i] = "-";
      arr.push(a)
     
    }
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(spinalCase('This Is Spinal Tap'));
```

For start, I'm trying to find UpperCase in string and change the space (that should be index before UpperCaseLetter) into dash "-". So newStr[i] returns not only UpperCase but spaces. Couldn't find any info about it. Any clues?

Comment: You never remove the spaces. You aren't converting characters to lowercase either. And why does the case even matter, if you only want to replace spaces with dashes?

Comment: This is more commonly called kebab-case or skewer-case FYI

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a couple simple string manipulations:

```js
let message = "This is Spinal Tap";
let toSpinalCase = s => s.replace(/ /gi, "-").toLowerCase();
console.log(toSpinalCase(message));
```

**EDIT:** Also, uppercase space and lowercase space have the same value, and therefore pass your condition.

Comment: Your code only converts the first space to a hyphen.

Comment: Hmmm…looking at it now

Comment: Fixed the issue @JLRishe

Comment: Yup, works now. I'm not the person who downvoted, though.

Comment: Lol. No problem. Thanks for catching the bug 